# Compare two lists in firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In android, I have a list generated by user input which needs to be compared to a list in Firebase Realtime Database. I want to compare if List 1 contains all the elements in List 2.
This data then needs to be displayed in FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter.
Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: For sure there is. What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: Nothing at comes to mind. I have an arrayList stored in database but using orderByChild also won't work because it compares only a value and does not compare a list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compare two lists in a single operation on the Firebase Realtime Database (nor on Cloud Firestore for those wondering). You will have to load the relevant lists from the database and perform the comparison inside your application code.